# iOS use a file with its partial file name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a app with several songs in it. The file format is: `index.name.mp3`

e.g.:

`1.Baby.mp3`

`2.Just Give Me A Reason.mp3`

I have a table view to show the songs, and store the index of the selected song

e.g. if user click `2.Just Give Me A Reason.mp3`, I will store the number 2 in NSUserDefault

So is there a way to get the file with it's partial name (e.g. prefix: 2, suffix mp3)

---

#### EDIT:

just in case it's not clear. I do **not** have a list of file names.

All I know is how many files there are (e.g. 50) and they have indices from (1 to 50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ORIGINAL ANSWER***

You have a list (or array) of songs that populate your tableview.

Assuming it's an array, you can enumerate through that array and simply look for a match to the song number:

```
NSString *getFilenameMatchingPrefix:(NSString *)prefixString
{
    // array of filenames is what populates your table view
    for(NSString *filename in arrayOfFilenames)
    {
        // convert filename to numeric prefix / name / suffix
        NSArray *filenameSplitOut = [filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        // the numeric prefix is what we want
        NSString *prefixFromFile = [filenameSplitOut objectAtIndex:0];
        if([prefixString isEqualToString:prefixFromFile])
        {
            // and we can return a filename, or we can return a file URL if we wanted...
            return(filename);
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

***NEWER ANSWER***

In general, it's better to use file URL's for doing anything with the file system.  But for simplicity's sake, we'll use file paths (which are NSString objects).

Given a "parent" folder that contains your mp3 files:

```
NSArray *getAllFilesInAFolder:(NSString *)parentFolderPath
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    arrayOfFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentFolderPath error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error getting contents of folder %@ - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return(arrayOfFiles):
}

NSString *getFilenameMatchingPrefix:(NSString *)prefixString
{
    // assuming you are hiding the .mp3 files in the resource folder of your app...
    NSArray *allMusicFiles = [self getAllFilesInAFolder:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

    // allMusicFiles is an array of NSString objects with filenames from the specified directory
    for(NSString *filename in allMusicFiles)
    {
        // convert filename to numeric prefix / name / suffix
        NSArray *filenameSplitOut = [filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        // the numeric prefix is what we want
        NSString *prefixFromFile = [filenameSplitOut objectAtIndex:0];
        if([prefixString isEqualToString:prefixFromFile])
        {
            // and we can return a filename, or we can return a file URL if we wanted...
            return(filename);
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an array of file names

Comment: then how are you populating your tableview?

Comment: there will be only one file that matches the number. prefix and .mp3 suffix. I get the string from the file name

Comment: is it gonna load all the rich media files to the memory?

Comment: the code I wrote is only loading the names of the files into an array

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here but you could also use the metadata from the mp3 file:[How to extract metadata from audio files on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723337/how-to-extract-metadata-from-audio-files-on-ios)

Just how songs in iTunes have titles and artist names, you can edit that and read that so you don't have to split strings.  That way you can get a lot more information like duration and artist etc.  Then if there is no metadata you can revert to breaking apart the filename.

I wouldn't go with filename alone because if you are using a server to host these files and you have files with the same name you would need to add something to differentiate the files like `(2)` or a random string and you don't want that in your app.  But thats just me and just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I will stick with file name since it's easier for me to manage on a computer